# Cherrypy missing errorevent if port is taken

Tags: python, cherrypy

if i start a cherrypy server and the port is taken i didn' t find any way to get to know about it:

```
import cherrypy

try:
    cherrypy.quickstart()
    print "Message1"
except:
    print "Message2"
```

. As i can see with pdb it forks another instance and this new will fail (give back the traceback) and i don' t see any chance to know about it. Also none of my print lines gets printed out.

How could i get notified from my code if the port is taken and the server didn' t start?

Answer (score 1):

I find that when my cherrypy app can't find an open port it's from an old instance in limbo.  So in linux I run...

```
$sudo ps -ef| grep python
root      2579     1  1 07:52 ?        00:02:19 /opt/Python-3.2/python /var/www/html/app/webapp.py
```

then...

```
 $kill -9 2579
```

You could achieve this in python but it should happen pretty rarely.  Let me know if you need instructions for windows.

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

You can verify the port before starting the server:

```
import sys

import cherrypy as cp
from cherrypy.process.servers import check_port

class Root(object):

    @cp.expose
    def index(self):
        return "Sample"

config = {'global': {'server.socket_port': 8080}}
cp.config.update(config)
port = cp.config.get('server.socket_port')
host = cp.config.get('server.socket_host', '127.0.0.1')
try:
    check_port(host, port)
except IOError:
    sys.stderr.write("The port %s is not free\n" % port)
    sys.exit(-1)
else:
    cp.quickstart(Root(), config=config)
```